# how to install rails using zip files downloaded from https://github.com/rails/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a fresher in rails.
I'd like to know how to install rails using zip files downloaded from https://github.com/rails/rails.

please kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

do you have a Unix based OS or Windows?

```
gem install rails
```

in the terminal should be all you need if you have ruby installed